# Table inside inline-block element breaks vertical alignment

Tags: html, html-table, css

When putting a table inside an inline-block element, the inline-block elements next to it are shifted down, instead of the tops of the elements being aligned.

### HTML

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<div>Element</div>
<div>Element</div>
```

### CSS

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

### Result

[image: http://i.gyazo.com/1734f13a3da745e22ada8c93d18f8d4b.png]

### Jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/dk39j/1/

**Why does this happen, and what can I do to prevent it?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set `vertical-align:top;` to the divs beside it

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dk39j/5/)

Comment: Your JS fiddle is the same as the one the poster has shown us. Here is an updated one: http://jsfiddle.net/SimplyAzuma/dk39j/3/ @JunM You beat me to it!

Comment: I'm also interested to know why it happens in this way. The default vertical alignment seems quite arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dk39j/4/)**

```
div {
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid #000;
vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: Why does it happen like this though? The top or bottom of the adjacent divs don't seem to be aligned to anywhere specific.